# C# DateTimePicker move to next date part

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I wish for my datetimepicker to have the same behavior asked here :
[Move to Following Date Part on Data Entry in DateTimePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517023/move-to-following-date-part-on-data-entry-in-datetimepicker/26731664)

To put it here, I wish to be moved to the next datepart after typing the day or month.

But I do not use Telerik and I do not wish to use SendKey in ValueChanged event like this solution :
[Avoid pressing . (period) key to move to next field in DateTime picker control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191972/avoid-pressing-period-key-to-move-to-next-field-in-datetime-picker-control)

Since I get InvalidOperationException.
And if possible I don't wish to have to create my own control like this :
[DateTimePicker automatically move to next datepart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399954/datetimepicker-automatically-move-to-next-datepart)

If it's not clear enough, the linked solution doesn't work well for me so I'm asking for other solution if they exist. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using something link this. Add your textbox to the TextChange method.

```
private void B_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox t = (TextBox)sender;
    string seperator = "/";
    switch(e.NewTextValue.Length)
    {
        case 2:
            t.Text += seperator;
            break;
        case 5:
            t.Text += seperator;
            break;
        case 10:
            t.Text += seperator;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The event textchanged of DateTimePicker does not have TextChangedEventArgs but EventArgs and even if I try to cast EventArgs, TextChangedEventArgs is not found. When I look for a ref to add I don't find anything related to TextChangedEvnetArg. So what am I missing or are there other ways ?

Comment: I Tried to replace NewTextValue by tostring to try and compile but the sender (datetimepicker) can't be cast as a Textbox. I did not seem to understand at first but are you suggesting that I use a textbox using you're method rather than a datetimepicker ?

Comment: What editor are you using? For this little example I use Visual studio 2015 with the lowest windows settings? I don't have a datetimepicker available. So thats why I used a Textbox.

Comment: I use VS 2015 as well, windows form application, .Net 4.5.2

Comment: Sorry, this was for Universal windows. not windows form application. I will look for an answer that will help you.